# Start terminal on start-up to LXDE

Tags: boot, lxde

I when booting the Raspberry Pi, I start directly to the LXDE environment. I would like to auto-start a terminal window, and in that terminal I would like to run a script (as root).

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up/8735#8735) for how to run a script when booting directly to the GUI (near the bottom of the answer).