# Why can't you connect Raspberry Pi to a Laptop via HDMI

Tags: hdmi, display

I have a Raspberry Pi 3b+. When I hook it up to my TV, which has HDMI input, it automatically boots up the pi and show the raspbian window. Although, when I connect it to my Laptop via HDMI there is no change in the display. So why does this happen and is there any way to get over this?

Comment: Your laptop **DOES NOT** have HDMI input, it's an output device. You can't connect an output to another output and expect it to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make desktop computer display RPi's desktop via HDMI?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12550/how-to-make-desktop-computer-display-rpis-desktop-via-hdmi)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most laptop hdmi ports are output not input. They are designed to connect a laptop to a monitor.

There are a few that have hdmi input.

You could use VNC Viewer on your laptop to view the Pi screen (by enabling VNC in Pi Configuration) over wifi/network.