# Open Chromium on start?

Tags: raspbian, boot, chromium

I've been looking at this quite a bit the last 24 hours and there are so many differing approaches and some maybe out of date. I've just installed a fresh copy of Raspbian as I think I broke the last one experimenting. I've installed Chromium and logged into my Google account so it can be my google cloud print server. I've also used raspi-config to set the Pi to boot to desktop.

Now all I want is for Chromium to open. I'm not bothered about what type of window it starts in or anything. I just need the Pi to be logged into my Google account on Chromium when the Pi starts up.

Could someone give me the definitive guide on the easiest way to do this?

Comment: You should use the "V" mark to tell your problem is resolved :)

Comment: Did you do any research on how to run software on startup?  If you did, you surely would have run into [this answer of mine](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/8735/8631).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was attempting to have chromium be my google print server. I found that as soon as I enabled this in chromium the chromium service was automatically starting on booting up the pi into LXDE. So that solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use init.d (because Raspbian is a debian-based distro). here you have a simple tutorial about how to use it to run software at boot :
http://xmodulo.com/2013/01/how-to-automatically-start-program-on-boot-in-debian.html

Comment: Thanks this is probably correct however I found that I didn't need to for this specific instance. See my own answer.