# start a lxterminal on startup

Tags: boot, lxterminal

I'm running raspabian on my pi and I would like for a lxterminal window to open every time I boot up. I'm not interested in running a script from boot, I only need the terminal to open.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute script on start-up](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up)

Comment: I have an answer on a similar question in stackoverflow: [Executing a script after the user has logged in, on Raspberry Pi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64957268/2430549).  My answer is oriented towards using `lxterminal` to accomplish that task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open the terminal on boot open file manager, navigate to /home/pi/Desktop and find the lxterminal shortcut. Right click and copy it.

Then go to /home/pi/.config/autostart (create these folders if they don't exist) and paste the file in there.

Reboot and lxterminal should open.

Though if you don't want the xwindows interface at all you can use the console by changing the start desktop on boot in raspi-config.

Comment: As of now this no longer works with the latest version of Raspbian.  Anything in autostart is ignored.

Comment: So what now....

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/

Using this

```
cd home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/
```

Open autostart

```
nano autostart
```

Add a `@lxterminal` in the last line. Press `CTRL+X` then `Y` and press `ENTER`.

Restart raspberry pi
OR 
Type `reboot` and press `ENTER`

After booting terminal pops up.

You can use this to make raspberry pi to execute programs at booting.
For executing that a program, like a python program that requests an API for information by reading an input.

Add that program in `.bashrc` file

Comment: As of now this no longer works with the latest version of Raspbian.  There is no lxsession folder.  I guess if you updated and it used to be there you could then move it back from your backup folder but if you're on a new install you'll have nothing to work with.