# Run bash script on startup

Tags: boot

I know this question has been asked before, but I can't find a fix for my problem, I just can't get my script to run on startup. Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

I put it into the `/etc/init.d` directory

Made sure it had executable by using `chmod 755 /etc/init.d/iptables.sh`

And done `touch /etc/rc3.d/S01iptables.sh`

But nothing :( ... Any suggestions?

> [ Nov 2017 ] The accepted answer here should be considered obsolete, please see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/75057/5538

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> *[Please see the note in the question regarding the obsolescence of this answer.]*

Try using this command to ensure your script is added to the boot sequence:

```
sudo update-rc.d /etc/init.d/nameofscript.sh defaults
```

Note that you can make a script executable using the +x option with chmod:

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/nameofscript.sh
```

Comment: Yeah the `update-rc.d` command worked :D ... I used it before, but it appeared to just return an error, so I ignored it Lol ... Thanks for the help :D

Comment: It would be `sudo update-rc.d nameofscript.sh defaults`, at least on Jessie, to avoid `update-rc.d: error: initscript does not exist: /etc/init.d//etc/init.d/nameofscript.sh`.

Comment: Does this script have to end within a reasonable time? Or can it be used to loop a video for infinity for example?

Answer (score 30):

You could also set up a cronjob ([see tutorial](http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/)) to make it run at startup

```
(sudo) crontab -e
```

only add `sudo` if your script needs superuser privileges. Then add this to your crontab:

```
@reboot /path/to/script.sh
```

Comment: I used this method to launch a script and it shutdown all ssh access for some reason. I had to mount the drive on another linux device and comment out the crontab line.

Answer (score 7):

You can add your script executable command to the bottom of `.bashrc` that will **run your script every time you log in**.

1. Make sure you are in the `pi` folder:

   ```
   $ cd ~
   ```
2. Create a file and write a script to run in the file:

   ```
   $ sudo nano superscript
   ```
3. Save and exit: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Open up `.bashrc` for configuration:

   ```
   $ sudo nano .bashrc
   ```
5. Scroll down to the bottom and add the line: `./superscript`
6. Save and exit: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

If you are looking for a solution that **works on bootup to the console**, take a look at [this link](http://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2012/06/raspberry-pi-run-program-at-start-up.html). Basic rundown:

1. Create a file for your startup script and write your script in the file:

   ```
   $ sudo nano /etc/init.d/superscript
   ```
2. Save and exit: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Make the script executable:

   ```
   $ sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/superscript
   ```
4. Register script to be run at startup:

   ```
   $ sudo update-rc.d superscript defaults
   ```

---

If you want a script to **run when you boot into the LXDE environment**, you could take a look at [this Raspberry Pi forum post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=11256):

1. Navigate to `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi`
2. Open the `autostart` file in that folder:

   ```
   $ sudo nano autostart
   ```
3. Add `@bash /path/to/scriptname &` on a new line.  If you want to run something like a python script, put something like `@python mypython.py` on a new line. Running a script file would be `@./superscript`, but for some reason the script runs in an infinite loop (perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1379904/1937270) will stop that).
4. Save and exit: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Restart your Raspberry Pi into the LXDE environment.

taken from [Execute script on start-up](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up)

Answer (score 1):

I usually just add the line to execute the script in `/etc/rc.local`, e.g. `/path/to/my/script.sh &`, before the last line that has `exit 0`. I added the "&" in order to send the script to the background in case it does not return, otherwise the next commands would not be executed.

So in your case I would simply add the two lines

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

at the end of `/etc/rc.local` just before `exit 0`.

Answer (score 0):

first of all create the script
for me it's `startup_file.sh`

move `startup_file.sh` to `/etc/init.d/`

make sure it is executable by :
`sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/startup_file.sh`

now use this command:
`sudo update-rc.d startup_file.sh defaults`

this one was suggested by [goldilocks](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/5538/goldilocks):

`sudo update-rc.d /etc/init.d/startup_file.sh defaults` ; it didn't work for me !!

just try one of the two should work