# Auto-start chromium on raspbian jessie - 11/2015

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, chromium

I have successfully loaded up chromium-browser on raspbian jessie and am trying to autostart chromium-browser --kiosk mode... and having no luck. I have tried several attempts with varying syntaxes including @chromium and @chromium-browser (w/out path). Any guidance much appreciated.

In the following directory - I have the following commands:
`/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
@sh ${HOME}/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autokey.sh
@/usr/bin/chromium-browser --noerordialogs --disable-session-crashed-bubble --disable-infobars --kiosk http://www.website.com
```

Comment: Should `--noerordialogs` be `--noerrdialogs`? See [here](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Comment: June 2018 - Chromium 56 - to suppress any errors it is common to use `--incognito`

Answer (score 28):

For Raspbian (Jessie), this solution worked for me:

Create a new .desktop file in `~/.config/autostart/`, e.g.

```
sudo nano ~/.config/autostart/autoChromium.desktop
```

Then add the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/chromium-browser --noerrdialogs --disable-session-crashed-bubble --disable-infobars --kiosk http://www.website.com
Hidden=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=AutoChromium
Name=AutoChromium
Comment=Start Chromium when GNOME starts
```

Then reboot. Chromium should automatically launch in kiosk mode after the desktop has loaded.

See [How to Add Startup Programs in GNOME 3.14 on Debian 8 ‘jessie’](https://web.archive.org/web/20170106235112/https://tranjeeshan.wordpress.com/2015/07/22/how-to-add-startup-programs-in-gnome-3-14-on-debian-8-jessie/) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: If it helps anyone else - Our Chromium was freezing periodically, so we created a cron job with this command to restart Chromium every hour: `0 * * * * killall chromium-browser; DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/chromium-browser --noerrdialogs --disable-session-crashed-bubble --disable-infobars --kiosk "http://www.website.com"&`

Answer (score 7):

### Raspbian Jessie Chromium boot to fullscreen:

*Loaded Chromium-browser for Raspbian Jessie based on this site:
-https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=121195&p=818455

*And got the Chromium "boot to fullscreen" from this guidance: 
site: http://www.0atman.com/auto-start-full-screen-web-page-on-raspbian-jessie-startup.html
Create a file called `~/.config/autostart/chromium.desktop` with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Connect
Comment=Checks internet connectivity
Exec=/usr/bin/chromium-browser -incognito --kiosk YOUR_WEB_ADDRESS
```

---

I needed to use Chromium for webrtc live video stream concepts; it looks to be running stable on a V9 codec streams... will try it out w/ H.264/5. I did have epiphany working but would crash after a few minutes of video feeds.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a soulution for running a script on startup:
[Run bash script on startup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15475/run-bash-script-on-startup)

You should try to put your command in a bash script.
E.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --noerordialogs --disable-session-crashed-bubble --disable-infobars --kiosk http://www.website.com
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x {path of the script}/nameofscript.sh
```

And try this:

```
sudo update-rc.d {path of the script}/nameofscript.sh defaults
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it out and up vote if works on Raspbian-Jessie. I know some has changed between Wheezy and Jessie... but your answer is much cleaner.  Appreciate the response!

Answer (score 2):

For Raspian Jessie with Raspberry 3, the right directory for me : ~/.config/autostart

Important : point before config

Because you have several autostart !
For me I use (pi user) : home/pic.config/autostart

Comment: The right directory for me  :/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

Comment: `sudo nano .config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` did the trick for me as well.