# Setting up a kiosk with Chromium

Tags: raspbian, chromium, kiosk

I'd like to put my Raspberry Pi into a kiosk mode with Chromium directed to my website but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work. I've been following a few different guides, and the code they have given me has all been slightly different so I'm not sure what exactly to follow.

So far I've tried a few different variations of changing the code in

`/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

with this:

```
#@xscreensaver -no-splash
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
@chromium --noerrdialogs --kiosk http://localhost --incognito
```

I also put the same code in

```
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
```

It still boots to just the desktop and I'm at a loss of what to do, as there doesn't seem to be very many tutorials discussing this and none that are recent.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Have a look [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37935/raspbian-jessie-install-chromium-browser-in-kiosk-mode) and let us know whether that's helpful or not.

Comment: [This helped me to autostart Chromium](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39181/39371)

Comment: Thanks for the help but that did not do the trick either. Honestly this is kind of ridiculous. This seems like a common thing people would want to do with their pi, yet there is little to no info on how to do it and the steps seems to change for every iteration of the OS.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 running Raspbian Jessie with Chromium 45 installed.  I found that you need to copy the existing autostart file to your local:

```
mkdir -p /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/
cp /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

So edit this local version:

```
nano /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

#@xscreensaver -no-splash  # comment this line out to disable screensaver
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
@chromium-browser --incognito --kiosk http://localhost/  # load chromium after boot and point to the localhost webserver in full screen mode
```

Save

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: FINALLY! The right file!

Comment: Before trying this, I want to know how to get out of Kiosk mode so I can make changes. Yet, I don't want anyone else to be able to do that.

Comment: I guess you could, at worst, SSH in from somewhere else and edit the file to remove the autostart options?

Comment: Yep.  `ssh -Y kioskname` into the system, then `sudo killall chromium-browser` will kill it.  Then you can just run Chromium via the ssh connection to change settings in the browser.  Then `sudo init 6` will cleanly reboot it.

Comment: this changed my default theme, how to fix back :)

Answer (score 6):

By default the Pi the auto-logon X environment is done with credentials of the `pi` user. The config setting's of the Xserver environment of this user is in `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`, NOT in `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` (this is the environment for the root user).