# Open chromium full screen on start up

Tags: boot, bash, cron, chromium

I would like to set up a couple of Raspberry Pis to open automatically chromium or any other browser available to at start-up, and in full screen mode.

I was wondering if any of you can help me. These will be placed as some fixed stations where I load up some URLs when raspberry pi starts.

Comment: You may want to check out fullpageos, and review the links to related questions on the right side of this page.

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40631/setting-up-a-kiosk-with-chromium Has all the info you need

Answer (score 47):

Edit this file

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

And add this:

```
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
@chromium-browser --kiosk http://google.com/  # load chromium after boot and open the website in full screen mode
```

Then reboot. Chromium should automatically launch in fullscreen mode after the desktop has loaded.

***Note**: The default file ( /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart ) is the global autostart and is executed each time a user logs into the desktop. In case you want to use local autostart, use `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`. Local autostart(s) are useful when you want to run different programs or configurations for each user.*

---

You can also add this line if you want the mouse to disappear:

```
@unclutter -idle 0.1 -root
```

(requires `sudo apt-get install unclutter`)

Comment: Nicely borrowed from another post. The hash comment indicates the URL was localhost. To make Chromium launch full screen you just need to add --kiosk or use xautomation to send F11.

Comment: I had to create the file, but this method still works in `Raspbian 10 (buster)`

Comment: Careful : with this solution, the desktop can be disabled. To keep the desktop on background, you are probably using NOOBs, so you may need to use the LXDE-pi folder : sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart.

Comment: @Jerry's comment refers to the pre-edit version of this answer, which proposed editing `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`. Using this path can lock you out of your OS, since if you close chromium, the OS gui will not be loaded behind it

Comment: I tested this on Raspberry Pi 4b using Bookworm and this does not work for me.

Answer (score 11):

on chromium you can use `--start-fullscreen` (like <kbd>F11</kbd>)

Comment: When I tried this with my browser open it didn't work... After closing my browser windows, running `chromium-browser --start-fullscreen` opened Chromium in fullscreen mode. Running `chromium-browser --start-fullscreen --kiosk` hid the "Press F11 to exit fullscreen" message

Comment: Worked for me in Raspbian 10. (Raspberry PI 4)