# Open chromium on boot

Tags: bash, chromium

I'm trying to open chromium when the Raspberry Pi 3B+ boots. I've found [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69204/open-chromium-full-screen-on-start-up), but my raspberry doesn't seem to have the `/home/pi/.config/lxsession` folder.
[image]

I tried creating the autostart file but It it won't work:

```
sudo nano /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Any clues?

Comment: You can follow my [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98944/launch-a-gui-tkinter-program-on-boot/98972#98972)

Comment: @Ephemeral It opens chromium, but it shows a message on the browser that says something like `Unsupported command-line flag: –no-sandbox`. If I follow your tutorial but I remove the no-sandbox flag it won't open.

Comment: ExecStart : `runuser -l  pi -c chromium-browser` ?

Comment: @Ephemeral Not working. How would be the full `ExecStart=` line?

Answer (score 1):

With System Unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start Chromium
After=graphical.target
Wants=graphical.target

[Service]
User=pi
Group=pi
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "export DISPLAY=:0; /usr/bin/chromium-browser https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com 2>/tmp/startup-error-chromium;"

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```