# Enable desktop on the raspberry pi

Tags: noobs, lxde, raspberry-pi-os

I was trying out booting my pi4 into a chromium kiosk mode for a demo and ran the commands from the following post:
[Open chromium full screen on start up](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69204/open-chromium-full-screen-on-start-up?newreg=7054241337e347739620f15af579db0e)

```
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
@chromium-browser --kiosk http://google.com/
```

Now when I went to that file again it seems to be empty and I'm not able to revert the change.

I tried looking for the reverse commands like

```
@xset s on
@xset s blank
```

Here's the output of I got from the commands in the comments:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 37 Jul 24 16:05 /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
@xset s on
@xset -dpms
@xset s blank
```

Comment: Before you ask, I am using NOOBS and I saw the 3rd comment that says to be careful AFTER doing it. I'm sorry, please help me. I don't want to format it again :(

Comment: You should tell us **what YOU did** NOTE that post is obsolete, file locations have changed and you SHOULD NOT use sudo in editing pi files

Comment: Dump NOOBS, use the direct image download https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-os/ Saves issues.  It's possible you did not save the files???

Comment: Please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/114625/edit) your question and add the output of these commands to it: `ls -l /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` and `cat /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`. Don't prepend `sudo` to the commands.

Comment: As you can see from the `cat` command, the file `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` does not contain what you want. From the command just replace `cat` with `sudo nano` and change the content of the autostart file. Don't forget to **save** the changes before closing the editor nano. After that check again with `cat /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`.

Comment: well, what should I put to get my desktop back?