# How to enable kiosk mode for a user other than "pi"

Tags: raspbian, kiosk

I am able to run the raspberry-pi in kiosk mode for 'pi' user in auto-login mode by editing the autostart file in `/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`.

I would like to do the same with the new user I have created 'userkiosk'. I have updated the `lightdm.conf` file so that the raspberry-pi auto logins with 'userkiosk' and I have also added the autostart file in `/home/userkiosk/.config/lxsession/LXDE-userkiosk/autostart` but the raspberry-pi is not going in kiosk mode and boots in desktop mode for 'userkiosk'

Is there a way I can get raspberry-pi in kiosk mode with 'userkiosk' ?

Comment: *I am able to run the raspberry-pi in kiosk mode for 'pi' user in auto-login mode*, how you did it?

Comment: I just followed the steps in this link and was able to set the pi in kiosk mode for user "pi"  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40631/setting-up-a-kiosk-with-chromium

Comment: Try `sudo adduser userkiosk2`, `sudo adduser userkiosk2 sudo` or `sudo adduser userkiosk2 pi`. I think it's your problem with user permission and group.