# 3.5" TFT screen keeps hibernating

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-jessie, power-management

I have been working with my RasPI 3 (using Jessie) for a little while on a project that I am SO CLOSE to finishing. Right now the main problem I am having is that I cannot keep the frigging screen from blacking out. I've managed to get the settings to work in the command line. But when I have made a script, it doesn't work (the script runs, but the power settings don't change).

A bit of background the project is using a 3.5" TFT screen so there is one odd command in there that I need (I'm guessing, I'm really at the point where I am plugging random code in and seeing what works). Anyway, if I go into the console and type these commands individually my screen stays on

```
export DISPLAY=:0
xset s noblank
xset s off
xset -dpms
```

I have put this in a startup script called startup.sh which I can run with a bash command. But my problem is that I have tried to have this bash script run at bootup following the instructions set out [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15475/run-bash-script-on-startup) but it doesn't the screen starts going blank again. I know the command is running because I have the startup script playing a sound and booting a browser into kiosk mode, but the power settings don't change.

What that stackexchange post says is to edit ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-

```
pi/autostart and add
@bash /path/to/scriptname
```

on a side note if a command works in the console, are you supposed to put the "@" symbol in the script or just put it in the script the way you type it in the console?

i.e. if this command works in the console

```
xset s noblank
```

Should I have it appear in the script as

```
@xset s noblank
```

or

```
xset s noblank
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  I had to get the script to sleep for a few seconds.  I guess something was conflicting in the boot sequence.  Once I let it boot up, wait for a bit of time and then run the script it worked.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.