# How do I make .sh run on boot to console?

Tags: boot, bash

I've made a basic script to run my Discord bot however, I can't get it to run on startup. I keep on getting an error saying. I'm using this [Run bash script on startup](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15475/run-bash-script-on-startup) and I still get an error " 'Run.sh' has missing LSB tags and overrides" Here is the script:

```
#! /bin/bash
#! /bin/sh

cd /media/root/NEW/ VOLUME/FurBot
node bot.js
```

I hope you can help :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately the Q&A you are consulting is

- Mostly obsolete, since the accepted answer uses SysV init style methods instead of systemd ones.  These are both [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) systems. The former is used on v. <= 7 Raspbian (unless I am remembering wrong, there's actually no < 7 since Raspbian follows Debian version numbering, and Debian has been evolving for a few decades).  The latter is used on the previous (8, jessie) and current (9, stretch) versions.  It supports SysV scripts for backward compatibility, *but*...
- The accepted answer in that Q&A does not actually explain how to write a SysV style script, just how to enable one.  And that's why you get the "missing LSB tags" error.  The script is missing a lot of things that would make it SysV compliant.

There's no point in learning how to write such a script, however (it is a bit ornate), since the system is obsolete.

The easiest thing to do there would be to just add something to the end of `/etc/rc.local` (but before the final `exit 0` line):

```sh
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin

cd /media/root/NEW\ VOLUME/FurBot
setsid node bot.js &> /dev/null
```

**Notice I inverted the slash in `NEW\ VOLUME`.** Command line parameters cannot have unescaped spaces in them; I presume that's what you mean to do.  You can instead use quotes:

```
cd "/media/root/NEW VOLUME/FurBot"
```

`setsid` maybe spurious here but doesn't hurt.  See `man setsid` for what it does.

If you want to get fancier, you can write a systemd service file for it --
 you will find a lot of examples of such for `node.js` online -- but if this works for you, then don't worry about it.

Comment: What does the `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin` line do?

Comment: @PhillHealey https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable) Setting it explicitly in `rc.local` here might be a bit paranoid, but harmless.

Comment: Fair enough. I just like to know what every line of code does before I use it for anything.

Answer (score 2):

There's an extra space in your `#!` line.  And you only need one.

This should work better:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /media/root/NEW/ VOLUME/FurBot
node bot.js
```

The extra `#!` is treated as a comment so it wasn't breaking anything.  But the extra space after the `!` will break it.

Comment: Good catch but that's not the reason for that error message.

Comment: Oh there's also a space in the `cd` path, that should probably be `NEW\ VOLUME`.