# Remove script from bootup into console

Tags: boot, script

I've read the answer to [Execute script on start-up](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up/8735#8735) on how to start a script from bootup to the console, which requires registering the script to be run at startup with the following command:

```
sudo update-rc.d superscript defaults
```

How do I stop this script from being executed from bootup into the console?  Do I simply delete the 'superscript' file or do I need to do something *in addition to* / *instead of* this?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo update-rc.d -f superscript remove
```

with the -f flag you don't have to delete the script, but of course you can...
Check `man update-rc.d` for details.