# How to turn Raspberry Pi off when HDMI is disconnected?

Tags: hdmi

How can I programmatically detect if the Raspberry Pi's HDMI cable is removed? I've tried tools like `xrandr`, but they give the same output regardless of whether the HDMI cable is plugged in or not.

Answer (score 8):

Try verifying the output of the file:

```
/sys/class/drm/card0-HDMI-A-1/status
```

The part `card0-HDMI-A-1` may be a little different (verify the parent directory for the correct file) and the content should be `connected` or `disconnected`. Also works for another connections, like `VGA`, `LVDS`, etc.
After this, simply make a script like:

```
while [ 1 ]
do
    STATUS=`cat /sys/class/drm/card0-HDMI-A-1/status`
    if [ "$STATUS" == "disconnected" ]; then
        echo "turning off"
        sudo shutdown now
    fi
    #sleep for 10 seconds and check again
    sleep 10
done
```

To run it automatically on background, follow [this link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/8735/29595).