# Can I execute a script before every login

Tags: python, server, script, login

I am planning to have a program that will need to connect to a server. 
I'd like to be able to send a encrypted password to my server.
The thing is, I need my decrypting script to be executed (everytime I need to login, not only at boot) before login in.

Is that possible?

Comment: Would executing the script as part of the login process work? You can add scripts that execute on login to `/etc/profile` (for all users) or `~./profile` if you're logging in at the console. There are many variations though. Are you logging in to a GUI or at the console? Do you want to script to execute if you connect remotely to your box (e.g. via `ssh`)? If at the console, you probably want to check out `man bash` and read the **INVOCATION** section.

Comment: If bobstro's suggestion does not lead you to a solution and you legitimately want help, you need to come up with a more detailed description of what you want to do.   Right now, particularly in light of your other question, this just reeks of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/2124) and many people who likely could help you will not be bothered to because of that.

Comment: also asked on U&L

Comment: Related to: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to execute this script every time a user login at your ssh server. You can place a script at `/etc/ssh/sshrc` the `sshrc` will automatically triggered when any user login into the server successfully.

This script is globally for all users they will login on the server. Also SFTP users, SSHFS users and all others they connect to your ssh-server.

We are using this feature to trigger a Slack Hook, to notify our team. For example you are able to get the ip-address of the person they would like login into our server.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/rc.local` and add the command you wish to run at the end of the script. Don't modify the already existing commands in the script however, as this is what sets up networking on boot.

Comment: The question explicitly says , *"I need my decrypting script to be executed (everytime I need to login, not only at boot)"*.  This will not do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is what you want, but if you use always the bash as the default shell, you can add your script in `~/.bashrc` and it will execute every time bash is executed (all logins). The bad side is that if you execute a simple `$ bash` order, the script will execute also.

Answer (score 0):

Add your script in `/etc/rc.local` to execute on boot
Add your script in `crontab` with the `@reboot` prefix to execute on boot, too
Add your script at then of the file `~/.bashrc` to execute AFTER login

Using `~/.bashrc` will execute your script after you login, also if you log from SSH.