# Activate virtualenv & start script on boot - RPi

Tags: python, pi-2

I am trying to start a python script that exists in a virtualenv from bootup on my RPi. From reading this [post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up) and the RPi [rc.local](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md) post I know that I will have to add something like this to /etc/rc.local to start the script:

```
python /home/pi/myscript.py
```

My question is how to activate the virtualenv that myscript.py depends on? The name on my virtualenv is cv3. This is what my ~/.profile contains:

```
# virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2.7
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

From what I read in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150671/python-how-to-set-virtualenv-for-a-crontab) I tried to activate the virtualenv by calling

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
source cv3/bin/activate
```

and then

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
source bin/activate
```

Neither of which worked so then I tried to implement the same code I use to activate the virtualenv manually which is cd'ing into my project directory, sourcing the profile and then calling workon cv3 as follows:

```
cd /my/project/folder
source ~/.profile
workon cv3
```

None of these solutions worked for me. Can someone please tell me how a virtualenv is activated from rc.local on a linux machine? I am running Noobs Raspbian on my RPi.

I would greatly appreciate any direction or advice you could offer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Using '. home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv3/bin/activate' to activate the virtualenv worked!

Comment: I wish you had said a little bit more about the solution...