# How to setup a C++ virtual environment on the raspberry pi 3?

Tags: software-installation, opencv, c++, software-compilation, computer-vision

I am currently trying to install openCV on my raspberry pi 3 and found this very nice tutorial to help me with that:http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/

However I don't know python. I'd like to setup a C++ virtual environment to program on my rpi instead. The reason I choose to use a virtual environment is because I am communication wih my rpi over SSH and don't have an external screen.

How can this be done? I didn't find any explanation online to do this.

What could eventually be an alternative?

Thank you

Comment: Just to be clear, Virtual environments are only for Python, not for c++

Comment: Possible Alternative [VirtualEnv on Boot](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36927/activate-virtualenv-start-script-on-boot-rpi)