# Running node.js script on start up

Tags: node.js

I have tried every method on here [Execute script on start-up](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up) 
and I still cannot get a .js file to run on start up. The file is very simple:

```
var noble = require('noble'); 
var request = require('request');
var http = require('http');
var trim = require('trim');
var LocalmacAddress  
require('getmac').getMac(function(err,LocalMacAddress){
if (err)  throw err;
console.log(LocalMacAddress); 
LocalmacAddress = LocalMacAddress   
});
noble.on('stateChange', function(state) {
 if (state === 'poweredOn')
  noble.startScanning([], true);
else
  noble.stopScanning(); 
});
noble.on('discover', function(peripheral) { 
  var macAddress = peripheral.uuid;
  var rss = peripheral.rssi;
  var s = URL HERE
console.log("http://dev.tester.com" + s);
var options = {
    host: 'dev.tester.com',
    path: s
};

callback = function(response) {
    var str = '';
    response.on('end', function (chunk) {
        str += chunk;
    });

response.on('end', function() {
    console.log(str);
});
}
http.request(options, callback).end();

});
```

I have added the to the `crontab`,

```
@reboot sudo /user/local/bin/node /home/pi/Desktop/Scan.js
```

I have added it to the `rc.local`

```
sudo /user/local/bin/node home/pi/Desktop/Scan.js
```

I have created a script `.superscript` and added it to the `init.d`

Comment: Did you mean `.superscript`, `./superscript`, or just `superscript`? I think it should be the latter, looking at the link you provided.

Comment: Ok I have figured out the problem ... the script was running before the wifi and Bluetooth was turned on so I added a wait timer that waited 30 seconds before the script runs.