# Run something after login

Tags: script

Let's say I used `raspi-config` to set my raspberry pi to auto-login to the 'pi' user. How would I have something run after login? My desired effect is that I plug in the pi, and without giving it any input, it boots to a desktop and then runs a shell script. I don't want the script to run before the auto-login - so I wouldn't want to put it in `/etc/init.d`

Comment: Do you want the script to run on boot, or login? These are different things.

Comment: after the autologin - sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: [This answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/44926/17451) works for me. I had to create the autostart directory as it wasn't present in Raspbian Jessie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this:

```
@reboot /path/to/python action.py
```

in your crontab. So, whenever you start your PI, it will automatically call your python script. Plus, this cron job should belong to your same **pi** user which is auto login in, otherwise it won't get called.

Comment: Yes, I've tried this, and it works. Thank you! You may want to change 'restart' to 'reboot' in your answer, though, as that is the actual command. Also, I don't know if this will apply to other cases, but I had to do `sudo crontab -e` and have the root crontab run my script.

Comment: @CharlesNoon edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`~/.bashrc` is the common way, I guess.

Comment: `.bashrc` is a poor choice as it will be run every time the user opens a terminal window.

Comment: So you are saying he meant the first login in his title? bashrc is s login script so I took his title literally.

Comment: `.bashrc` is not just a login script. It runs every time bash is started. It sounds like the OP wants a script to run when the machine starts, and then logs in. `.bashrc` will run every time the bash interpreter is started. Which means it's happening a lot more often than when the user logs in.

Comment: When you open a terminal you logon to the terminal. I got docked 2 points because you don't know what a login script is. Haven't you ever seen the messages where user x logs onto TTY a and TTY b etc.

Comment: The user is asking about a desktop interface. `.bashrc` will run whenever a bash prompt is started. It's fundamnetally different than what the user asked for. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29#When_started_as_an_interactive_login_shell

Comment: Yeah, this isn't really what I'm looking for. This would only run after I started a terminal emulator, if I booted to desktop. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: I runs when you login