# Raspberry Pi and Arduino Notification System

Tags: python, serial, arduino, home-automation

I am trying to make a notification system using an ultrasonic sensor with an Arduino to detect when there is something in the way of a door, once the obstruction is detected, I have a timer start, once the timer goes off data is sent to the Raspberry Pi.  I have figured out how to get the Raspberry Pi to read the data through the serial port when it is sent from the Arduino and email a notification, but it requires me to install `py.serial` in the terminal and initialize the reading on Python to begin with.  I don't want the system to be dependent on a monitor or a person to be constantly typing in the command.

Is there any way to automate this process?

This is what I have for the Arduino:

```
 int vcc = 2;
 int trig = 3; 
 int echo = 4; 
 int gnd = 5;  
long previouscm = 0; // will store last time LED was updated
 long previousinches= 0; // will store last time LED was updated
 long interval = 25;           // distance of door
 unsigned long previousMillis = 0;


void setup() {
  //initialize USS
  pinMode (vcc,OUTPUT);
  pinMode (gnd,OUTPUT);
  // initialize serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
//constantly checking distance
//act based on this change
// establish variables for duration of the ping,
// and the distance result in inches and centimeters:
unsigned long currentMillis = millis(); 
long duration, inches, cm, currentinch, currentcm; //variables
long timespan;

//setup USS to read
pinMode(trig, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(trig, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(2);
digitalWrite(trig, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(5);
digitalWrite(trig, LOW);
pinMode(echo, INPUT);
duration = pulseIn(echo, HIGH);

// convert the time into a distance
inches = duration / 74 / 2;
cm = duration / 29 / 2;
//previouscm=0 interval= 25 cm(to door)
if (cm - previouscm < interval) {
  previousMillis= currentMillis - previousMillis;
}
    delay(300000);
  if (previousMillis=60000){
    Serial.print(inches);
    Serial.print("in, ");
    Serial.print(cm);
    Serial.print("cm");
    Serial.println();
  }
}
```

and this is what I have for the Raspberry Pi:

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)

while 1:
    data = ser.readline()[:-2]
    if data:
        import smtplib

        content = ("Blood has been stored for 72 hours.")

        mail = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)

        mail.ehlo()

        mail.starttls()

        mail.login('email','pass')

        mail.sendmail('email','toemail',content) 

        mail.close()

        print("Sent")
```

To install pyserial in the terminal I always have to input:

```
cd pyserial-3.0.1
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: If you edit your question to include what you have to type, I'll try to indicate how to convert it to a command to run at boot.

Comment: I put all my info in the question thank you so much

Comment: Please consider investigating in the direction pointed to by Mark's answer. The details of the script as inserted by the last edit will probably not help any further.

Comment: Please check this http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up

Comment: Are you installing this on multiple Pis?  You should only need to run the command "cd pyserial-3.0.1; sudo python setup.py install" once.

Comment: Just one, errors pop up if I don't reinstall every time I run the program, it may just be coincidence.

Comment: It should only be installed once.  Could you edit your question and add the error messages which you see?

Answer (score 1):

I think your question simplifies to "how do I run a command automatically at startup?"

The answer to that is to put the command into a file such as `/etc/rc.local`.