# Running startup script WITHOUT creating a service?

Tags: boot, services

I would like to create a script,which will stop/kill a daemon after this one has been started. Therefore my script hat to be executed at boot time after the one which is going to be killed, but I don´t want it to be executed/launched as a service, is that possible in raspbian?

I have seen [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up) but there is explained more as service, I have tried it but it doesn´t seem to work in my case, so I was wondering if I could do it in the old fashion way of setting the sort of S0....sh at /etc/init.d/

Thanks in advance,

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you would like to kill a daemon with a script and not simply disable the respective service in the first place... e.g.:

```
sudo update-rc.d <your daemon service> disable
```

But you could create a script that checks if the daemon in question is running and kills it if so. You could than use `cron` to execute this script at regular intervals e.g. every minute or so. Or you can use the special string `@reboot` to invoke a command at boot time ([example](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-execute-cron-job-after-system-reboot/)). For the last you would need to make sure that the `cron` service starts after the daemon you want to kill.