# Cannot auto-start Java application upon X session login

Tags: lxde

I am reading [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up#8735), and I edited `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`, by appending the following line:

```
@sudo java -jar /home/pi/Documents/devel/MyProject/MyProject.jar
```

But nothing happens when I reboot the Pi, the program does not get started. I will also want to have a terminal window if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have packaged my app now with a shell script that runs the java command. Then I have a `my-app.desktop` file like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=lxterminal -e "my-app-script"
```

And this goes into `.config/autostart`.