# How to write service on Jessie

Tags: raspbian-jessie, services, init.d, systemd

I would like to write a service with the standard start, stop, restart, status interface and that runs on startup and restarts if killed.  However, in researching solutions, I've discovered that there are multiple ways to do this with varying levels of support, and that the latest Debian release changed its support for installing services.

What's the simplest supported way to create a service in Jessie?  What's the most canonical way to create a service in Jessie?  Is `/etc/init.d` only used for deprecated approaches?

Comment: Although it does not fulfill all your criteria, you could first have a look [at this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/52056/5538).  Beyond that, questions about [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) are more appropriate to our big sibling site [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).   There is copious documentation online, and also a slew of man pages (try `apropos systemd`; the ones most applicable will probably be `systemd.unit`, `systemd.service`, and `systemd.exec` as most of the directives are in those).

Comment: Service creation differs across Linux distributions. Asking questions specific to the latest Raspbian distro is off topic?

Comment: *"Service creation differs across Linux distributions."* -> No, service creation differs from one [init system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) to another.  Once upon a time distros were almost all essentially **SysV** based, and Debian has been the big holdout on this.  Since Debian abandoned that w/ v.8 (jessie) and Ubuntu finished with **upstart**, both in favour of **systemd** (which began with Fedora), they are now for the most part all unified again.

Comment: I close questions like this partially for the benefit of the poster: It makes more sense, and you will get better results, if you research from the general to the specific rather vice versa.  For example, command line utilities specified by [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) such as [`ls`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html), (`man`, `crontab`, `nice`, etc.) may still differ slightly from one implementation to another, but:

Comment: On GNU/Linux (including all the aforementioned distros), the implementation is usually the same, since it's from [GNU coreutils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities).  However, even with this, there may be minor difference due to version (which Debian lags behind on by policy) and choices made during compilation.  So, indeed, it may turn that there is some peculiar quirk to the `ls` used on Raspbian that differentiates it from most other distros.

Comment: However, don't assume that there is, and therefore the POSIX documentation for ls is no good to you, because you must have the "raspberry pi docs" (or Raspbian docs).  Instead assume it's the same as everywhere else and research it that way.   I've used systemd on a variety of distributions and (at least in the context of what you are asking about) it is the same everywhere.   Since the Raspberry Pi only represents a small percentage of linux users, this means you have a much broader range of material to draw on.

Comment: We do often field general linux questions here *at our discretion* ("our" being the community which elected me), but with most things, particularly this, you will get better advice on U&L.  However, this question would likely quickly be closed as a duplicate and/or slammed as reflecting a lack of research effort, which is why I did not migrate it directly.   I'm not accusing of you of laziness or blaming you for your ignorance, BTW; linux can remain a bewildering world for people even after a few years of casual use.

Comment: What I am trying to say is, "Hey, you've got your head stuck in the sand".  The other major reason I close questions like this is to spare people having to write, e.g., an explanation of `ls` for Raspberry Pi users.  There's no need for that and spoon feeding beyond a certain point is **not** a favour to anyone.  Good luck -- like a lot of things linux, systemd does not have the "consumer orientation" people are used to in an operating system (it's skewed toward the "power user"), and the docs reflect this, but don't mistake that for incoherence or dysfunction.