# omxplayer won't play on boot

Tags: raspbian, python, boot, script, omxplayer

I have a python script that needs to run the omxplayer after the pi is finished booting on the latest version of Raspbian whit Pixel.

I have tried the 3 different methods from the accepted answer here : [Execute script on start-up](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up)

The script does execute, but the video player won't start. (Nothing appears on the screen)

If I run the script by hand, the video works. I have tried with both LXDE enabled and disabled.

How can I get omxplayer to display the video when executing after a reboot?

```
os.system(`killall omxplayer.bin`)
omxc = subprocess.Popen([`omxplayer`, `-b`, `dronesunset.mp4`])
```

Comment: Can you try passing the full path to the mp4 file ? maybe its a issue of wrong working directory  ... also noticed the first line says `osxplayer.bin`. i am assuming you mean `omxplayer.bin` (note the 's' instead of 'm')

Comment: good catch for the path! I changed it to absolute path and still same behavior. Works when launching manually, but not on login. the osxplayer was just a typo when I wrote the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to do to get it to work : 
instead of using .bashrc to start it, I had to :

**run when booted into the LXDE environment** see : [Execute script on start-up](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up)

and thanks to Shreyas comment, make sure that the path to the video is absolute to prevent working directory confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely do this without the need for a GUI desktop or logging in. I used this technique to have a RPi Zero 1.3 (no network) boot directly into `omxplayer` continually looping a video -- a 2 hour aquarium loop in my case. Here's how I did it using `systemd`:

1. Create a file in `/etc/systemd/system/omxplayer.service` containing:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Ambient scenery display
   Before=systemd-user-sessions.service

   [Service]
   TimeoutStartSec=0

   ExecStart=/usr/bin/omxplayer -r --loop --vol -6000 -o hdmi "/path/to/video.mp4"
   Type=simple
   User=youruser

   ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall omxplayer
   User=youruser
   ```
2. Enable the service with `sudo systemctl enable omxplayer`.

The RPi should boot and launch `omxplayer` early in the boot process. The console is useless at this point, and the Pixel desktop inaccessible unless you add something to kill `omxplayer` when needed. The player runs in the background, so pressing `[esc]` won't exit it. If the RPi is networked, you can access it via the network normally.

Note the use of the `omxplayer` parameters: `--vol -6000` for silent (change to suit), `-r` to adjust the framerate to the video, `--loop` to loop continuously (with a short blank between loops, unfortunately), and  `-o hdmi` to force HDMI output.

Answer (score 1):

omxplaer requires lxterminal to run, so:

In `~/.config/autostart/omxplayer.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=lxterminal -l -e "omxplayer --loop --no-osd -o hdmi /home/pi/Videos/vid.mp4 > /dev/null"
```

Then:

```
reboot
```

Comment: I'm working on an app that runs on boot instead of desktop environment (fullscreen app that is the only purpose of this RPi), and I couldn't get video playing from there. I just edited .xsessionrc and replaced `exec /path/to/myapp` with `exec lxterminal -e /path/to/myapp` and everything runs fine. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can play videos without logging into an account first. However, you can create a new account with autologin  to do it:

Add a new user if you don't want to put autologin on your personal account:
`sudo adduser videouser`

If your script needs root permissions: (skip if you are using your account)
`sudo visudo`

Then navigate to bottom and add/edit: (skip if you are using your account)
`videouser  ALL=(ALL) ALL`

Once that's done, type `nano ~/.bashrc` (may need sudo). Go to the very bottom. Any valid bash that you put here will be run when the account has logged in:

`omxplayer -b /absolute/path/to/video.mp4`

Comment: One of the methods I tried to auto-start the script waits for the pi to auto-login into the user pi.

Comment: What exactly did you try? To help you further we need more info. Can you show us the **exact** command you are using to launch your python script?

Comment: In my original question I state that I tried all the methods of the accepted answer with a link...

Comment: What command did you add to your `bashrc` file? Because if you are using the same one as from the link then it might not work, because he's trying to launch a browser and you're trying to launch a python script.

Comment: python  /absolute/path/to/script.py and in my python script there are the lines I posted in my question.

Comment: Ok, where is your python script on your system?

Comment: /home/pi/DustBuster/DustBuster.py and the user that auto login is pi. The script and the video works perfectly when I run then in terminal with user pi using the same command than in the bashrc.

Comment: And where is your python installation?

Comment: it's the default python installation from rasbpian. The script and the video works perfectly when I run them in terminal with user pi using the same command than in the bashrc.

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Comment: I appreciate that you are trying to help me, but please read my question! The script runs when auto starting(I can make python do stuff)! It's the omxplayer that is not displaying the video.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Try using `-o HDMI` flag when running your video. That will force it to use the HDMI output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59381/discussion-between-camp-bell-and-antoinelev).

Answer (score 0):

Put the script in .config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

I've done something similar but with a bash script.