# How to autostart Kodi at boot?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, kodi

I've got Kodi 17 Krypton and would like to start the app automatically when the Raspberry Pi boots.

How can I do this?

Comment: Already a question on this. It covers command line and GUI programs. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up

Comment: Check out the link below to autostart kodi 17.5 on Raspbian Jessie and Stretch, be sure to check out the comment for the error solutions, lines 6 and 15 are incorrect in the readme. https://gist.github.com/Cyberek/33af1b92c071791a71aa8bccf87b8a3a

Comment: Direct link for correct approach on latest update (Raspbian Stretch & Kodi 17.5): https://gist.github.com/Cyberek/33af1b92c071791a71aa8bccf87b8a3a#gistcomment-2304207 (I found it via this link, so commenting for future searches)

Comment: I simply added `@kodi` in `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` as instructed on https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-kodi-raspbian-media-center/

Comment: create the service! instructs here https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1207376

Comment: This command is all you need. "echo "@kodi" >> ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart" as per https://mtantawy.com/how-to-autostart-kodi-on-raspberry-pi-using-only-one-command/ . It worked for me.

Comment: Using systemd (with big advantage of restarting Kodi in case of crashes) https://github.com/brunetton/kodi_systemd/blob/main/kodi.service

Answer (score 12):

Aside from the answers already provided by others, you could also utilise the crontab to do this fairly easily provided that you have already disabled starting Raspbian GUI on startup via `raspi-config`.

```bsh
sudo crontab -e
```

Then add the following line:

```
@reboot kodi --standalone
```

Thorough description on my blog [post](https://www.leowkahman.com/2016/03/05/lamp-stack-on-raspberry-pi-with-kodi-running-at-startup/).

Comment: This makes my system freeze at startup

Comment: @ablmf Try running Kodi directly to see if that freezes. I remember trying out Raspbian Buster where Kodi ran very slowly. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=244069. I reverted back to Stretch.

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: just one important thing to add to this, if you run `sudo crontab -e` you will be editing root's crontab, and thus kodi will run as root. You might wanna run `crontab -e` instead, to run as a normal user. Also, if you were running kodi as a normal user before, you will not have any of your configuration by launching kodi as root.

Answer (score 8):

If you are running Raspbian 10 (based on Debian Buster), then the proper way to add it is to add `@kodi` to the file `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` which will automatically start it only for your user. If you add it to `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` then it will affect all users.

[The Kodi Wiki](https://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Autostart_Kodi_for_Linux#Configure_Kodi_to_autostart) suggests that you run the following:

```
sudo sed -i "1i @kodi" /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

The `sed -i "1i @kodi"` part simply puts the `@kodi` line at the top of the file. Putting it at the top of the file may prevent the desktop from showing up for a brief second. Exiting Kodi will bring you to the desktop in either case.

You can find out which Raspbian version you are running with:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 \n \l
```

Answer (score 4):

For Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (Stretch), the following is used to autostart kodi at boot:

1. Edit file /etc/default/kodi and set

   `ENABLED=1`
2. Unmask and enable the kodi systemd service:

   `sudo systemctl unmask kodi.service`

   `sudo systemctl enable kodi.service`

Comment: what if kodi.service does not exist in the first place?

Comment: I have tested only on raspbian which provices a kodi deb package with the "kodi.service" convenience. If your installation does not have such an init script, maybe you can create one as described in the kodi wiki: http://kodi.wiki/view/Archive:HOW-TO:Autostart_Kodi_for_Linux

Comment: no kodi file in /etc/default/ on mine (raspbian 9.6 stretch)

Comment: [`kodi.service` is no longer shipped with the kodi `apt` package](https://salsa.debian.org/multimedia-team/kodi/-/commit/7a371bfd9daf9b918a5d944cf1a04f71c37b387d) (change committed 2018-04-28). The recommendation from that commit is to use the LXDE autostart instead, as other answers suggest.

Answer (score 3):

In my case to append "kodi &" at the end of "/etc/rc.local" does not work.

Neither the option of "ENABLED=1" into "/etc/default/kodi", because the file and the startup scripts does not exist.

I have tried to append the following instead that is working for me:

```
sudo -b -u pi kodi
```

By the way, if somebody knows how to set up it using a service, and respawn the service when it shut down for any reason, it could be very cool.

I am using raspbian as linux distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't take this the wrong way but would OpenELEC be more suitable? 
If not, add it to /etc/rc.local just above the last line.

> Kodi &

Something like that but you may need the full path.

Answer (score 0):

To have it start automatically you just have to do

```
sudo systemctl enable kodi
```

and later if you want to remove it

```
sudo systemctl disable kodi
```

Comment: [`kodi.service` is no longer shipped with the kodi `apt` package](https://salsa.debian.org/multimedia-team/kodi/-/commit/7a371bfd9daf9b918a5d944cf1a04f71c37b387d) (change committed 2018-04-28). The recommendation from that commit is to use the LXDE autostart instead, as other answers suggest.

Answer (score -1):

Start by running

```
crontab -e
```

Then run

```
@reboot sudo -b -u pi kodi
```

Comment: Could you please add some sort of explanation to your answer?