# Scripts running at boot up

Tags: boot, boot-issues

I am trying to run this program at boot up. Its file path is /home/pi/shutdown.py. The reason why I ask is because I have tried to use multiple different boot up sequences listed in the following website [Execute script on start-up](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up)

### Is there any way to get this script to run in the background at boot (I have to run other scripts as well)?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)                                                                                                    
#setting the giop pins up note how this is pin 23 on the pi
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)                                                                       
#the pin is pulled down and will wait for a raiceing edge

def printFunction(channel):
    GPIO.cleanup()
    print("power button was pushed will shut down now")
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system("sudo shutdown -h now")

GPIO.add_event_detect(23, GPIO.RISING, callback=printFunction, bouncetime=300)
```

Comment: @randall https://superuser.com/questions/685471/how-can-i-run-a-command-after-boot

Comment: What happened when you used the other methods you linked? Did you get an error, or did it simply fail silently?