# How to autorun a backround script after LXDE boots up

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, boot, lxde, kiosk

I have been trying to make a autostart script to opens up a web page in fullscreen mode

> sudo nano .config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
>
> @chromium-browser --kiosk --disable-restore-session-state www.domain.com

this one works but i also want to refresh the page like every 10 minutes. I'm trying to write a code to do that

> sudo nano .config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
>
> @/usr/bin/python /home/pi/PATH/TO/SCRİPT.py

like this should work but im not sure how a loop or delay will effect the system. Should i make it run at backround and if so how can i?

I know there are many answers [Execute script on start-up](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up) in this topic but i couldn't find an answer to refreshing and making a loop at autostart script.

This is my first question. Please let me know if i make some formatting errors.

---

How to refresh and creating script is explained in **https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=163316** this topic but still i have no idea how that will effect my system and is it okay to do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you own the web-page being displayed, just add a META refresh tag to it like this:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="600">
```

If you don't own the page being displayed, you can wrap it in an invisible IFrame that refreshes it's contents every so often.

Here's some code for that IFrame I found somewhere on the net (not my code! - If I could attribute it I would)...

```
<html>
    <style>
        body{padding:0;margin:0;}
        iframe{width: 100%;height: 100%;border:0;}
    </style>

    <iframe id="theframe" src="http://example.com"></iframe>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var iframeEl = document.getElementById('theframe');
        var url = iframeEl.src;
        iframeEl.src = 'about:blank';
        setInterval(function() {
            var ts = new Date().getTime()
            iframeEl.src = url + '?ts=' + ts;
        }, 600000 /* 10 minutes in milliseconds  */ );
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Or, you could install a Chrome extension that refreshes your pages automatically.