# Excute python file on start-up

Tags: python, boot, systemd-startup

I have a simple python file(no GUI) that I'd like it to run in the background at start-up of raspberry pi 3b.
I checked out this post [Execute script on start-up](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up)
But it didn't specify what to do with python file though.
Python script:

```
import time
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
while True:
    sounda=pygame.mixer.Sound("test.wav")
    sounda.play()
    time.sleep(5)
```

The complete file is at: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_MPR121/blob/master/examples/playtest.py However I'm unable to make it work, so just used a simpler version instead.
Appreciate the help.

Comment: posted the wrong thread location. That script wasn't the one I was looking at.

Comment: **DO NOT** put ANYTHING in `.bashrc` - this is extremely poor practice as it will run EVERY time you execute a non-login shell. It is intended to initialise the shell. The other suggestions are obsolete `SysV` code.

Comment: That's why I'm asking here for another solution.

Comment: There are Hundreds (if not thousands) of similar questions on this site. Have you looked? Unfortunately many wrong or obsolete - even then **IT DEPENDS** on the script - the question is unanswerable without.

Comment: Just added script, and yes I have looked. The variety of solutions confused me.

Comment: i'd recommend taking a look at [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md) ... you want to put your python script launch command in `/etc/rc.local` (since its been a while since i last used that, i am not sure if it is still the recommended way)

Answer (score 2):

A *systemd* unit will do the job. Create a new one with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --force --full edit myPythonScript.service
```

In the editor insert these statements, save it and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=running my python script
Wants=multi-user.target
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=pi     # or must it run as root? Then omit this line
ExecStart=/home/pi/myPythonScript.py   # or where your program is

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable the new service:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable myPythonScript.service
```

reboot.

Check with:

```
rpi ~$ systemctl status myPythonScript.service
rpi ~$ systemctl cat myPythonScript.service
```

Edit again with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --full edit myPythonScript.service
```

I don't know if it runs on the first attempt. There may be some edge conditions I don't know, something like user rights, environment etc. It is no problem to configure these dependencies. The problem is to find them ;-) Give me a comment under this answer if it doesn't run at first go.