# python start on boot

Tags: python, boot, sudo, pixel

i am trying to get my WS2812 NeoPixel python sketch to run at boot, i used a tutorial https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/connect-control-raspberry-pi-ws2812-rgb-led-strips/ it install the correct files and such and all works fine when i run the commands in terminal the lights do as they are meant to, an just trying to figure out how to make them start on boot, i am still really new to all of this

```
the 3 commands i use to run the python script as follow 

cd rpi_ws281x/

cd python

sudo PYTHONPATH=".:build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7" python examples/strandtest.py
```

any help would be much approached

i have tried following a tutorial on hear explaining what to do and it always comes back with an error file or directory not found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excute python file on start-up](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/85962/excute-python-file-on-start-up)

Comment: Your line with `sudo` looks wrong. Usually anything all caps with an = should appear first thing on the line (they are environment variables). The corrected line would be `PYTHONPATH=".:build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7" sudo python examples/strandtest.py`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `cron` for this. To schedule a `cron` job, you will use the `crontab` utility. Start by reading the `man` pages for `cron` and `crontab`. You could also search the Internet for information resources, and find something similar to [this guide](https://www.ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/).

Once you have the gist (general idea) of this, try this from the command line of your RPi:

```
crontab -e
```

This should launch a text editor (`nano` or `pico` IIRC) that opens with your existing `crontab` in it. You will edit this file to add the line you need to start your program at boot time. At the bottom of your existing `crontab` file, add something like this:

```
@reboot ( /bin/sleep 30; /usr/bin/python /path/to/your/PythonProgram.py  > /home/pi/cronjoblog 2>&1)
```

For an explanation of what this command does & why we do it this way, see [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/105326/83790). If you have any issues getting this to work, please edit your OP, and we'll try to help.

---

P.S. The [crontab Guru](https://crontab.guru/#30_0,1,2,3_*_*_*) is a useful asset to bookmark.

Comment: This is a duplicate answer.

Comment: Do you have a link to the duplicate?

Comment: [duplicate**s**](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/83790/seamus?tab=answers)

Comment: @Ingo: Sorry if I'm being thick, but I see no dupes on the link you provided. Let's try it this way: [This is one](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/105538/83790); can you provide the URL of the other - the duplicate in other words.?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a command for your python code to run at every start-up. All that you need is just add a command to `rc.local` using this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Add the following command for python2 to the file before `exit 0`:

```
sudo python2 /path/to/file.py
```

And add the following command for python3:

```
sudo python3 /path/to/file.py
```

If your code is running with any endless loop like `while True`, then use `ampersand (&)` at the end of the command like this:

```
sudo python3 /path/to/file.py &
```

Comment: Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.

Comment: Ohk. I'll start working on from from now onwards then. Thanks a lot