# Python script not running on boot from /etc/rc.local

Tags: python-2.x

I'm trying to ran python 2.7 script on boot, and did following:

- `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`
- Modified file before exit 0 with line:
- `sudo /usr/bin/python /home/smart-scale/scoreboard/main.py &`
- That command works on ssh terminal
- Added "`#!/usr/bin/python`" to the top of script

When I reboot and check if its running with htop, it's not.

Ideas?

EDIT: no quatation marks used

Comment: Is the path /home/smart-scale/scoreboard/main.py definitely correct?

Comment: rc.local is an unreliable way of running a script. You do not use sudo, and no one can tell what you are trying to do.

Comment: Does the command-line that you typed into the /etc/rc.local file include the quotation marks? If so, remove them. Having them in a shell script such as /etc/rc.local will cause the entire line to be perceived by the shell as a single command with a very long and unusual name.

Comment: @CoderMike The path is correct as the command works when running through ssh terminal. There is no quatation marks

Comment: Since you accepted a cron answer, your question is essentially a dupe of [Execute script on start-up](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Millways has pointed out in his comment, using `rc.local` is probably not the best way to do this. You should try something else. There are two alternatives (maybe more); I'll describe one of them here; the one I feel is the simplest and easiest:

Start your `crontab` editor as follows:

```
crontab -e
```

Add the following line to your `crontab` file:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python /home/smart-scale/scoreboard/main.py
```

Depending upon the resources required in your Python script, and the timing of related events in the boot process, you may find that your script does not run with this `crontab` entry. If that's the case, simply delay execution of the script to give all the required resources to get up and running using the `sleep` directive as follows:

```
@reboot /bin/sleep 30; /usr/bin/python /home/smart-scale/scoreboard/main.py
```

It may also be helpful to redirect the `stderr` output (error messages) to a file (`/home/pi/cronjoblog` in this example) for diagnosis and debugging. You can do that by this simple addition to the same line in your `crontab` file:

```
@reboot (/bin/sleep 30; /usr/bin/python /home/smart-scale/scoreboard/main.py  > /home/pi/cronjoblog 2>&1)
```

Once you've finished your edits to the `crontab` file, save and exit. When you reboot, your script will run.

Comment: thank you @Seamus! This one worked. It might have been because of the delay, as the script is trying to connect to a usb device. But i will definetly use this crontab method going forward

Comment: @dev-1000: I'm glad it helped. But before becoming too attached to `cron`, you should spend some time learning about [`systemd`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/systemd-essentials-working-with-services-units-and-the-journal) as it's the "new way", and has some distinct advantages over `cron`. ALSO: [Please read this.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason is that environment variables are missing, such as `PYTHONHOME`.

Try to start your script from the command line with

```
env -i sudo /usr/bin/python /home/smart-scale/scoreboard/main.py
```

Add missing variables to the script until it runs.

For a list of Python related environment variables, use

```
env | grep ^PYTHON | sort
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your */etc/rc.local* file does not contain the literal quotation marks that you surrounded your command-line with in your question. If so, remove them; they are the problem.

I also assume you've used the search feature in *htop* to confirm that the process is definitely not running. If you only look at the default view, *htop* sorts processes according to how busy they are. It's possible your script is running but is blocked for some reason (such as waiting for input). If so, it might not show up near the top of your list.

If your script is definitely not running, or if it is running but not doing whatever you want it do do, one debugging tip is to capture the output and error messages into a file so that you can read it after it has run and (presumably) failed. Note that the syntax is very particular. Don't use quote marks, and make sure you preserve the spaces as follows.

```
sudo /usr/bin/python /home/smart-scale/scoreboard/main.py > /tmp/scoreboard.log 2>&1 &
```

The first part of the command has your original command line, minus the *&* at the end.

The *> /tmp/scoreboard.log* part is a shell redirection and it causes any printed output from your program to be captured (redirected) to a file called */tmp/scoreboard.log*. I made up that name, you can change it to whatever you like. It should be a complete fully-qualified file path, though.

The *2>&1* part is a different kind of redirection that causes error messages to also be captured in the same file as the output messages, in order of occurrence with the output messages.

The final *&* puts the command in the background just as you had in your original command line.

Reboot and use *nano*, *cat*, or *less* to check the contents of the file */tmp/scoreboard.log*. With luck it will tell you what is wrong and you can correct it. If you don't understand what the output means, update your question with the output and we'll try again.

P.S. Note that this debugging command is for troubleshooting only; if you leave this change in indefinitely, you might fill up your disk with logging data.

P.P.S. A couple other comments that probably have nothing to do with your problem.

First, the use of *sudo* in */etc/rc.local* commands is not needed, as everything run from rc.local is already run as root. It's harmless to leave in, but I recommend removing because later on you may wonder why it's there.

Second, you don't need *#!/usr/bin/python* (which is called a bang path) in your python script file since you are explicitly calling */usr/bin/python* on the command line. You could remove the bangpath from the python script, or you could leave it in and remove the explicit call to */usr/bin/python* in the *rc.local* script. If you do the latter, you have to make sure the script it executable (*chmod a_x /home/smart-scale/scoreboard/main.py*). If all of that is new to you, don't worry too much. Leaving it as-is is not hurting anything, and in fact is quite common. I just wanted to let you know they are two different ways to get the same effect, i.e. to get your script run by a python interpreter.

Comment: In addition to any debugging suggestions you should be aware that using `/etc/rc.local` may have timing problems in general with unexpected side effects. This is because rc.local is only emulated by *systemd*. Look at [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/) for its limitations.

Answer (score -1):

I struggled with using etc/rc.local to run a python script at startup for several months. Nothing happened with no error messages. It seems that there is limit to the number of characters you can have in the path/filename string, just as there was in MSDOS. (ducks from a clap of thunder and a deluge of locusts). It is about 32 characters. Life is too short to be more specific. Shortening the filename, which had grown like topsy during development, but which hadn't caused Python to choke, did the trick in my case. Your line "/home/smart-scale/scoreboard/main.py" is 36 characters long, and will certainly fail, if my theory is correct.
Test the line you intend to put into rc.local in a Terminal window. If it doesn't work there you will at least get the error message that the file can't be found. If it does work there then it will/should work in rc.local.

Comment: In general it is not a good idea to ride a dead horse with rc.local.

Comment: Now that I have grasped the character limit concept, recounted above, which had caused me considerablr grief, I find that rc.local is far from dead, but is in fact quite useful and reliable for starting "headless" Raspi projects.

Comment: Please understand the last sentence at [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/), saying: "*Note that there are some areas where systemd currently provides a certain amount of compatibility where we expect this compatibility to be removed eventually.*"

Comment: What you have 'grasped' is an incorrect notion. `rc.local` is not long for this world; whatever utility it once had is being slowly but surely removed. If you want to continue to use it, I'd suggest you find a 15-year-old distribution of FreeBSD. Not meant to be rude or insulting - we're just trying to share the facts with you. If you don't like the facts, we understand - but facts are facts.

Comment: Have you not noticed that this thread is about the Raspberry Pi, so references to 15 year old FreeBSD are not awfully useful, relevant or based on facts.