# Getting a .sh to run automatically

Tags: noobs

I am in day 5 of my crash course of learning how to use a Raspberry Pi (or any Linux platform) for the first time.
I have an .sh named "startup.sh" file located at "/home/pi/". 
I have tried several different forums and nothing has helped.
I just want this .sh to run at startup.

The script I have made, mounts 2 drives from a wireless home server, and once connect it starts a slide show from some pictures on drives using a screensaver method. I needed there to be a delay between connecting to the wifi before mounting the drives, and a few seconds before it starts the slide show (to allow the mounting process to happen). I've tried using the ./superscript in the .bashrc (accessed using sudo nano .bashrc). I've also tried using the crontab by adding "@reboot /home/pi/startup.sh" at the end.
Here is what my crontab and script look like. [Link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1r0d7jybBgwkSQbmO6BylTotqLUH2avrXd0nDabe8JXM/edit?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute script on start-up](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up)

Comment: There are many ways to do this so this is a rather open-ended question.  Rather than trying to describe all the possible methods, maybe you can help narrow the question down a bit.  e.g. You can run process as part of the system boot process (not tied to any specific user or login).  There are also ways to tie it to a specific user (e.g. it will run when the user logs in).  Does this program require a GUI?  If you can provide a few details, we can probably point you to resources to guide you through a specific method likely to be useful to you.

Comment: The scrip I have made, mounts 2 drives from a wirless home server, and once connect it starts a slide show from some pictures on drives using a screensaver method. I needed there to be a delay between connecting to the wifi before mounting the drives, and a few seconds before it starts the slide show (to allow the mounting process to happen).

Comment: I've tried using the ./superscript in the .bashrc (accessed using sudo nano .bashrc)
I've also tried using the crontag by adding "@reboot   /home/pi/startup.sh" at the end

Comment: @user46629 You need to make sure that the problem is not within your script. Are you completely sure that the script _isn't_ running on startup?

Comment: @scitronboy yes I'm sure.

Comment: I've had the system run untouched after reboot for an hour will no sign of the script doing anything.

Comment: Add `exec &> /home/pi/startup.log` to your script print the output of your script to a logfile.

Answer (score 1):

If your shell script runs from your command line as user `pi`, but DOESN'T run under cron, the two most likely reasons are:
1. Environment variables are different, typically the PATH: *the `cron` user does not have the same `environment` as user pi does.* You can easily overcome this by using a full path for all executables in your script.
2. Resources required in your script are not yet available when `cron` starts: `cron` does not know the status of services when it starts (for example, it doesn't know if the network is up). You can usually overcome this by using a brief `sleep` before executing your script.

You can help yourself by redirecting `stderr` for your script to a file. You currently have no visibility of error messages - a bit like driving with blinders on.

Also, make sure your script has an appropriate `shebang` line at the top so the system will know which interpreter to use.

Here's an example crontab entry that might work for you:

```
@reboot (/bin/sleep 30; /home/pi/startup.sh > /home/pi/cronjoblog 2>&1)
```

This will cause `cron` to sleep for 30 seconds before running your script. If you get any errors, they will be written to the file `/home/pi/cronjoblog`

Try this. Let us know if it still doesn't work, and we'll try to help you sort that.

Comment: What do you mean my script has to have the appropriate "shebang" line?

Comment: This is the commands my script has right is, "sudo mount -t cifs -o.....", "sudo mount -t cifs -o.....", "sleep 10", "feh -Y -x -q -D 5 -B black -F -Z -z -r........."

Comment: Edit your question, please - we need to see your `crontab`; we can't do this via Comments. In the meantime, put this redirection after the command in your `crontab`: ` > /home/pi/cronjoblog 2>&1`

Comment: I've only added 2 lines to the crontab. "0 0 * * * * root reboot" and "@reboot ( /bin/sleep 30; /home/pi/startup.sh > /home/pi/cronjoblog 2>&1)"

Comment: Here's a google doc with the crontab and script. [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1r0d7jybBgwkSQbmO6BylTotqLUH2avrXd0nDabe8JXM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @user46629: This really should go in your question - that's to your benefit, as more people who can help will see it. Simply click the [`edit`](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/95217/edit) link below your question, and add the information.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize I could edit the question