# Execute a script on startup in latest NOOBS OS - Raspberry - Pi 3B+

Tags: raspbian, noobs, script, lxsession

Actually I have went through this [stack answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/8735/104644) and followed the **3rd Type** for running the script on startup, and It works like a charm for previous version of NOOBS. Today I downloaded the latest zip file

```
NOOBS OS Version 
Version:3.0.1
Release date:2019-04-08
```

I tried to put my scripts inside my 
`~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi` path but unfortunately there is not folder called lxsession inside the .config folder

[image]

when using `.bashrc` method 
[image]
bashrc method runs the script while opening new terminal like that.

Is there any solution to run my python script after startup ?

Comment: `there is not folder called lxsession inside the .config folder`  ... what is preventing you from creating the folder?

Comment: The methods you are trying are not to start a script on startup. They are used to start a script at login. What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

NOOBS is not an OS

The link you listed is for an obsolete OS, and has no relevance the current Raspbian GUI or to Linux systemd.

You need to list your script to get a definitive answer, it depends on what it does.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md shows how to start a general (non GUI) script.