# Mounting USB-HDD with NTFS filesystem on Raspbian boot

Tags: raspbian, mount, fstab, reboot, ntfs

I use Raspberry pi3+ as a small NAS (with Samba). I have to use a couple of HDDs in usb-sata cases with NTFS file system. Raspbian mounts them automatically on boot in /media/pi directory. I don't like this behavior: I'd like every particular drive to be mounted to a specific directory in /home/pi, and I have to manually unmount them  from /media, than remount to, say, /home/pi/ntfsdv1 as well as chown /home/pi/ntfsdrv1 to pi user.

How do I make Raspbian: 
1) Stop mounting usb drives to /media directory
2) Mount drives automatically on boot to the folders I deesire (fstab maybe?)
3) Automatically chown the content of the mounted drive to pi user  (so I don't get problems with accessing root's files with smb)
?

Comment: I'd suggest running a script on boot that unmounts those drives, remounts them and runs chown. To get an idea of how to make a script run on startup, see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up This is preferrable to altering the default behavior because undoing it is as simple as removing your startup script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To automount your USB drives to a directory of your choosing:

In accordance w/ `man fstab`:

> The second field (fs_file).
>                 This field describes the mount point (target) for the filesystem.  For swap partitions, this  field  should
>                 be specified as `none`. If the name of the mount point contains spaces these can be escaped as `\040`.

For example, to mount a drive w/ `LABEL=PASSPORT2TB` on `/home/pi/mntPassport`, a line similar to this in your `/etc/fstab` should work:

```
LABEL=PASSPORT2TB /home/pi/mntPassport ext4 rw,user,nofail 0 0
```

You'll need to change `ext4` to `NTFS`, and of course using `LABEL` to id the drive is only one option... again, `man fstab` is your friend.

2. WRT `chown`: You may find that `pi` automatically gets ownership, but if not:

```
sudo chown -R pi:pi /home/pi/mntPassport/YourFolderName
```

Let us know how this works, or if you have questions. You may also wish to peruse [this *recipe* on github](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/FileShare.md).