# Execute new tmux session then start nodejs script on start-up

Tags: raspbian, boot

I'm hosting a discord bot on my raspberry pi and I want it to create new session on start up

I have tried with edit `rc.local` :

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
  /usr/bin/tmux new-session -d "cd /home/pi/myBot; sudo node index.js"
fi

exit 0
```

However it didn't work, when I check with `tmux a`, it said `no sessions`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute script on start-up](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up)

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I tried it and it didn't work either, the service said it's running but the bot didn't

Comment: I assume that it doesn't recognize ether tmux nor node, I even tried with full path `/usr/bin/tmux` and `/usr/bin/node`

Comment: Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it. Does the command run from the commandline successfully? Does it has any output on the console or graphical?